# I am getting error on places Api "over query limit"

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am getting an error "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" and on my console and I see response code 403 on Places API metrics.

I have ensured that billing is enabled and there is no cap on the limit for the API.

I was using Places SDK Android and now I am trying to use Places API on the same project and I get the error "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT".

Answer (score 0):

Aside from billing account not enabled and exceeded cap, you usually get that error when any of the following is true:

- An API key is missing from the request.
- The provided API key is invalid.
- Billing is not associated with your project.
- The provided method of payment is no longer valid (for example, a
  credit card has expired).
- You have exceeded the QPS limits for Places API.

More details on that can be found on this link:
https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?#over-limit-key-error

For further assistance, kindly file a support case via https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support in order to open personalized communication channel.

Answer (score 0):

OK disabled and enabled the API and made a new API key. That solved my issue. I have no explanation why it works by disabling and re-enabling the API.